# How to mock Gson in mockito java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, gson

I am autowiring Gson object defined in configuration class since A Gson object is created for each method call, which is expensive

```
   @Configuration
    public class ConfigClass {
      @Bean
      public Gson gsonInstance(){
        Gson GSON = new Gson();
        return GSON;
      }
```

In my service class i autowired gson

```
    @Service
    public class ServiceClass {
        @Autowired
        private Gson gson;
          
    public List<Car> getCars(String garageNum, String locationNum) {
    //Gson gson = new Gson(); Avoid this
    ResponseEntity<String> respStr =  this.restTemplate.exchange("/cars/{garageNum}/location/{locationNum}", HttpMethod.GET,null, String.class, garageNum, locationNum);
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken< List<Car>>(){}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(respStr.getBody(), collectionType);
}
```

Now i am unable to mock the GSON in mockito unit test

Answer (score -1):

You mock Gson in Mockito by adding a dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
<version>2.13.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

or you can alter your service class

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass {
    protected Gson gson;

    CurrentAffairsRepository(Gson gson){
        this.gson = gson;
    }
```

Now in your test class

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ServiceClassTest {

```
@InjectMocks
private ServiceClass serviceClass;
@Mock
private RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;
private static final String GET_CARS_URL = "/car/{garageNum}/location/{locationNum}";

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    Gson mockgson = new Gson();
    serviceClass.restTemplate = mockRestTemplate;
    serviceClass.gson = mockgson;
}

@Test
void testGetCurrentAffairs() {
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntityMock = new ResponseEntity<>(
            "[{\"externalId\":\"123\"}]",
            header,
            HttpStatus.OK
    );
    
    when(mockRestTemplate.exchange( GET_CARS_URL, HttpMethod.GET,null, String.class, "12", "13")).thenReturn(responseEntityMock);
    List<Cars> cars = serviceClass.getCars("12","13");
    assertEquals(1,cars.size());
}
```

}